# How to extract all dependencies from a Windows file in Python or grep

Tags: windows, dependencies

How do I extract all the dependencies from a Windows file in Python? So I basically want to extract all the used exe,dll,osx,sys etc. files.

I would like to to this in Python or directly with grep.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Pefile](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/pefile/1.2.10-63) can help you parse PE executables. You can find some usage examples on the project's [page](http://code.google.com/p/pefile/wiki/UsageExamples).